# Comic strip where Adolf Hitler says something like "I am a victim too"

Tags: identification-request, comics

A comic strip I saw in the last 20-30 years had Adolf Hitler say something like "I am a victim too". Not sure if Hitler said it, or if someone was telling him he was a victim too.  It was a statement on people at that time claiming to be victims when if anything they were the bad guys.  It may have been in Wiley Miller's *Non Sequitur*.